# PHP - while Loop issue

Tags: php, arrays, json, sql-server

I have fetch data from Ms SQL Server 2008. I have execute three query execute in one time and one statement. First Query is student Detail and Marks, Second query is total marks and Percentage, Third query is Exam name.

I have Problem is that while loop display only one record but actually,there is four record. three record is not display.Percentage value display null.

Marks1.php

```
$reg = $_GET['reg'];

$sql = "select b.std_Name,d.Standard,e.Division,a.ExamDate,f.subject,a.ExamName,a.Marks,a.TotalMarks,a.PassingMarks 
                                  from Marks_mas a  inner join std_reg b on a.regno=b.regno 
                                  INNER JOIN Subject_mas as f ON a.Subject_ID = f.Subject_ID 
                                  inner join StandardMaster d on a.standard = d.STDID 
                                  inner join DivisionMaster e on a.Division = e.DivisionID 
                                  where a.RegNo= '$reg' order by a.ExamDate; select   sum(a.Marks) as Marks,sum(a.TotalMarks) as TotalMarks, (sum(a.Marks)/sum(a.TotalMarks) * 100) as Percentage 
                                   from Marks_mas a 
                                   where a.RegNo= '$reg'; select distinct ExamName From Marks_mas;";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);

$result = array(); 

 if (!empty($stmt)) {
        // check for empty result
        if (sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt) > 0) {

            //$stmt = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);



             while ($stmt = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $marks = array();
            $marks["std_Name"] = $stmt["std_Name"];
            $marks["Standard"] = $stmt["Standard"];
            $marks["Division"] = $stmt["Division"];
            $marks["ExamDate"] = $stmt["ExamDate"];
            $marks["subject"] = $stmt["subject"];
            $marks["ExamName"] = $stmt["ExamName"];
            $marks["Marks"] = $stmt["Marks"];
            $marks["TotalMarks"] = $stmt["TotalMarks"];
            $marks["PassingMarks"] = $stmt["PassingMarks"];


            $total = array();
            $total["Marks"] = $stmt["Marks"];
            $total["TotalMarks"] = $stmt["TotalMarks"];
            $total["Percentage"] = $stmt["Percentage"];

            $exam = array();
            $exam["ExamName"] = $stmt["ExamName"];

            }




             // success
            $result["success"] = 1;


            // user node
            $result["marks"] = array();
            $result["total"] = array();
            $result["exam"] = array();


            array_push($result["marks"],$marks);
            array_push($result["total"],$total);
            array_push($result["exam"],$exam);

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($result);


        } else {
            // no product found
            $result["success"] = 0;
            $result["message"] = "No product found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($result);

        }

        //sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
        sqlsrv_close($conn); //Close the connnection first  

    }
```

Give Error In Image:

[image]

In image marks array record display one but actually there four record. three record is not display.in total array percentage value given null.

Below give actual Result.In marks array display Four Record and total array give percentage value.

I have need this Result:

```
{"success":1,"marks":[{"std_Name":"VIVEK SANAPARA","Standard":"12-SCI-CE","Division":"A","ExamDate":{"date":"2016-10-06 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"UTC"},"subject":"MATHS","ExamName":"WT","Marks":"30.00","TotalMarks":"30.00","PassingMarks":"10"},{"std_Name":"VIVEK SANAPARA","Standard":"12-SCI-CE","Division":"A","ExamDate":{"date":"2016-10-07 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Kolkata"},"subject":"PHYSICS","ExamName":"WT","Marks":"15.00","TotalMarks":"30.00","PassingMarks":"10"},{"std_Name":"VIVEK SANAPARA","Standard":"12-SCI-CE","Division":"A","ExamDate":{"date":"2016-10-08 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Kolkata"},"subject":"PHYSICS","ExamName":"WT","Marks":"25.00","TotalMarks":"30.00","PassingMarks":"10"},{"std_Name":"VIVEK SANAPARA","Standard":"12-SCI-CE","Division":"A","ExamDate":{"date":"2016-11-22 00:00:00.000000","timezone_type":3,"timezone":"Asia\/Kolkata"},"subject":"PHYSICS","ExamName":"WT","Marks":"25.00","TotalMarks":"30.00","PassingMarks":"10"},],"total":[{"Marks":"30.00","TotalMarks":"30.00","Percentage":"79.166600"}],"exam":[{"ExamName":"WT"}]}
```

Comment: Your trying to run multiple select statements in one query and then expecting to get the values back separately.  Try splitting them into individual queries - unless you can make it into 1 select statement.

Comment: i was tried it. give me a example

Answer (score 0):

Use left join I assume the `Marks_mas` is the master table that connects to the other tables.

```
$sql = "select b.std_Name,d.Standard,e.Division,a.ExamDate,f.subject,a.ExamName,a.Marks,a.TotalMarks,a.PassingMarks 
                              from Marks_mas a  LEFT join std_reg b on a.regno=b.regno 
                              LEFT JOIN Subject_mas as f ON a.Subject_ID = f.Subject_ID 
                              LEFT join StandardMaster d on a.standard = d.STDID 
                              LEFT join DivisionMaster e on a.Division = e.DivisionID 
                              where a.RegNo= '$reg' order by a.ExamDate; select   sum(a.Marks) as Marks,sum(a.TotalMarks) as TotalMarks, (sum(a.Marks)/sum(a.TotalMarks) * 100) as Percentage 
                               from Marks_mas a 
                               where a.RegNo= '$reg'; select distinct ExamName From Marks_mas;";
```